# vb.net DrawString X-Position

Tags: vb.net, positioning, drawstring

I have problems with positioning within the DrawString method. However, only on the X axis.
No matter what value I recommend for the distance from above - it fits. Therefore, I assume that I have made everything right.
For example, An X in Arial with font size 10, the letter is slightly more than 0.5 mm too far right. If I try it with font size 600, it is more than 35 mm too far right. I suspect that something has to be adjusted depending on the font size and it has nothing to do with the dimensions of the Graphics object.
Does anyone have ideas / experiences / a formula?

If code examples are needed, I can supply them.

Comment: _If code examples are needed, I can supply them._. That would go well to providing a [mcve] so please do include your code examples.

Comment: Your code is almost always needed since only having a description usually doesn't give us the full picture. For your specific question a screenshot showing your problem along with your code _**(code posted as plain text!)**_ would be the best.

Comment: In my Sub that `handles Me.PrintPage` I set `ThisGraphics = e.Graphics`

`ThisGraphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter`

While Printing:

`NewStartPositionX = StartPositionX - OffsetX()`
`ThisGraphics.DrawString(Text, Font, Brush, NewStartPositionX, NewStartPositionY)`

`OffsetX()` returns `CInt(PrintArea.X * FactorInch) \ 100 + ThisGraphics.Transform.OffsetX`

That works fine with the NewStartPositionY

Comment: _the letter is slightly more than 0.5 mm too far right_ - this is meaningless without some context.  The letter is 0.5mm too far to the right of _what_?  I cannot understand what your problem is.  Also, don't add code to comments.  Please _edit_ your question and supply the code there.